# DataTable hide specific rows with a button

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable, datatables

i'm currently working on a project in which i have a DataTable that is filled using Ajax (and data from database)
This DataTable contains all the customers orders with different types for exemple: shipped, canceled ...etc
I want to have a button that shows only the rows with canceled state 

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`column.search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search())

```
<input type="button" class="show_only_canceled" value="Show Only Canceled" />
...
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();

const CANCELED_STATE_COLUMN = 3; //column number wherever you store state 

$('.show_only_canceled').on( 'click', function () {
    table
        .columns( 3 ) 
        .search(CANCELED_STATE_COLUMN)
        .draw();
} );
```

Comment: it works but then what i want is that when i unclick, the filtre shows everything but the canceled state heres my code   `if ($('#hide').is(":checked"))
            {
                dataTable
                    .columns( 3 )
                    .search("Annulée")
                    .draw();

            }else{
                dataTable
                    .search( '' )
                    .columns().search( '' )
                    .draw();
            }` the only issue is that is that when it's not clicked it shows everything , not everything but the canceled state

Comment: in this case you should use RegExp as your search term to exclude particular results.. maybe something like `table.search('(?!canceled)'+search, true, false).draw();` see here https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/24696/exclude-expression-onglobal-search